# How can I load all the audio files inside a folder using Bevy?

Tags: audio, rust, assets, bevy

I'm trying to make a music player where the user can play any audio file inside a folder. To do this, I'm trying to spawn entities containing a `Music` component and an `Sound(Handle<AudioSource>)` component. In the Bevy examples, I saw this line of code that seemed to be what I wanted:

```rust
// You can load all assets in a folder like this. They will be loaded in parallel without blocking
let _scenes: Vec<HandleUntyped> = asset_server.load_folder("models/monkey").unwrap();
```

Here is the function I wrote:

```rust
fn load_audio(mut commands: Commands, asset_server: Res<AssetServer>, audio: Res<Audio>) {
    let music = asset_server.load_folder("music").unwrap();
    for song in music {
        commands.spawn((
            Music,
            Sound(song),
        ));
    }
}
```

This code gives a compilation error because `song` is of the type `HandleUntyped`. My first idea was to convert `HandleUntyped` into `Handle<AudioSource>`. I have to imagine there is some way to do this, or else `HanldeUntyped` would be pretty useless, but looking through the Bevy docs I can't find any way to do this. `Handle::<AudioSource>::from(song)` didn't work. I've also considered using the `std::fs` library to get all the audio files in the directory and load them each individually with Bevy, but the existence of the `load_folder` method seems to imply that Bevy has a more elegant and simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course immediately after giving up the search and posting a question, I find the answer. `HandleUntyped` implements the [`typed()`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.3.0/bevy/asset/struct.HandleUntyped.html#method.typed) function, which converts it into a typed `Handle`. All I needed to do was replace `Sound(song)` with `Sound(song.typed())`.